# Cisco VPN:Secure vpn connection terminated locally by the client

Tags: vpn, cisco

I get this error when trying to connect to a Cisco VPN:

```
Secure vpn connection terminated locally by the client
Reason 412: The remote peer is no longer responding
```

- I tried to disable firewall and reinstall the VPN
- Transparent tunneling is put on: IPSec over UDP (NAT/PAT)
- Nothing is blocked and the port is listening.
- Other IPs are connecting.

What else could cause this error?

Comment: Dead Peer Detection or idle timeout?  This is set in the Group Policy -> More Options in ASDM.